# hbase.master.port overridden programmatically?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I installed hbase from cloudera 5.3.3 distribution and as I run the hbase everything seems to be working fine...

When I try assign hbase.master.port via /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml it does not pick it from there.

I see this from master node info http://MASTERNODE:60010/conf

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.master.port</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <source>programatically</source>
</property>
```

hbase distribution: 0.98.6-cdh5.3.3

What does this '**programmatically**' mean and how can I disable/override it ?

Comment: What are you trying to achive here, are you trying to override Hbase master default port from 60010 ?

Comment: 60010 is hbase.master.info.port ,and master.info.port is now changing everytime with every restart, this way hard to get good network approval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*answering my own question :(*

as i just figured out the hbase standalone mode do not takes hbase.master.port into account
https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/cdh4.5.0-release/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/LocalHBaseCluster.java#L141

standalone mode:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_hbase_standalone_start.html

only way to assign a port is to setup ,at least a Pseudo-Distributed Mode,
see this: 
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_hbase_pseudo_configure.html

Comment: (first link is broken now) https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/0.98/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/LocalHBaseCluster.java#L144

Answer (score 2):

This means, its being set in some app/code.
Are you using Cloduera Manager?
 You will need to set it in Cloduera Manager. If you are not using Cloudera Manager, then you will need to modify hbase-site.xml for HBase cluster and do a reboot of HBase cluster.

Comment: Hi Anil, I  am not using cloudera manager, and I tried to use hbase-site.xml to configure it. Restarting hbase-master did not help.

Comment: did you modify hbase-site.xml of node that is running hbase master? Is there any paritcular reason you dont want to use Cloudera Manager? It will make administration very easy.

Comment: ok. in that case, can you post this on cloudera forums. This is more of a question to cloudera(https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!forum/cdh-user) at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Since version [1.4.2](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/1.4.2/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/LocalHBaseCluster.java#L147) there's `hbase.localcluster.assign.random.ports` option which prevents ports overriding